# Passing pointers for memory allocation inside a function?

Tags: c, database, malloc, argument-passing

I need to allocate arrays of structures in a bunch of different places in my program, thus putting the work inside a function (VS 2010).  Compiler gives warning about uninitialized variable used.  So how do I pass it, and how to declare it in the function.  I've tried many variations of "`&`" and "`*`", to no avail.

(I apologize in advance if my code causes any form of nausea...I'm an English major.)

```
struct s_stream {
int blah;
};

void xxyz(void)
{
    struct s_stream **StreamBuild;
    char *memBlock_1;

    xalloc(StreamBuild, memBlock_1, 20);
}



void xalloc(struct s_stream **StreamStruct, char *memBlock, int structCount)
{
    int i = sizeof(struct s_stream *);
    if ((StreamStruct=(struct s_stream **) malloc(structCount * i)) == NULL)
        fatal("failed struct pointer alloc");

    int blockSize = structCount * sizeof(struct s_stream);
    if ((memBlock = (char *) malloc(blockSize)) == NULL)
        fatal("failed struct memBlock alloc");

    // initialize all structure elements to 0 (including booleans)
    memset(memBlock, 0, blockSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < structCount; ++i)
       StreamStruct[i]=(struct s_stream *) &memBlock[i*sizeof(struct s_stream) ];
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do - is it to dynamically allocate arrays of `struct s_stream` objects?

Comment: Tell us the exact warning from the compiler. In particular, which line of code does the compiler dislike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a *copy* of the pointer `memBlock_1` to `xalloc`, so the address returned by `malloc` is written to the copy and never reaches the calling function. Since you presumably want the address to be available to `xxyz` in `memBlock_1`, you have to pass a pointer-to-pointer-to-char as the second argument,

```
void xalloc(..., char **memBlock, ...)
```

and call it with `xalloc(..., &memBlock_1, ...);`. In the body of `xalloc`, replace all occurrences of `memBlock` with `*memblock`, e.g. `(*memblock = malloc(blockSize)) == NULL` (no need to cast).

Analogously, the `StreamStruct` parameter of `xalloc` never changes the `StreamBuild` pointer-to-pointer-to-struct s_stream in `xxyz`. If I interpret your intentions correctly, you would also have to add a pointer layer to that parameter, `void xalloc(struct s_stream ***StreamStruct, ..., ...)`, pass the address of `StreamBuild` in the call, `xalloc(&StreamBuild, ..., ...)` and dereference the pointer in the function body, e.g. `(*StreamStruct = malloc(structCount * i)) == NULL`.

Comment: I followed your advice; 2 remaining issues: compiler won't allow: (*StreamStruct = malloc(structCount * i))... I have to cast to (struct s_stream **).  The other issue is the last 2 lines where I loop thru and assign the pointers to a block of memory: for (int i = 0; i < structCount; ++i)
       StreamStruct[i]=(struct s_stream *) &memBlock[i*sizeof(struct s_stream) ];
}
I get an unhandled exception. I tried lots of difft permutations of * and & on StreamStruct and memBlock, but no go...

Comment: If you need to cast the result of `malloc`, that means you're compiling your programme as C++, not as C. That's probably not a big deal, the two have enough in common that simple programmes compile and work as both (after casting `malloc` returns etc.). In the loop, it should be `for(...) (*StreamStruct)[i] = &memBlock[...];` - unless I overlook something. Hmm, 'unhandled exception'. Yep, C++. If you're compiling as C++ (not a bad idea with Microsoft's compiler, that doesn't support C99, but it's fine as a C++ compiler), you might consider writing C++, using `new` and such.

Comment: which is correct?   for(...) (*StreamStruct)[i] = &memBlock[...];   OR     for(...) (*StreamStruct)[i] = (*memBlock)[...];   ?  The latter seems to work, and is consistent with what you said earlier...

Comment: Oops, forgot that `memBlock` also got an additional layer, `(*StreamStruct)[i] = &((*memBlock)[...]);` should be the one.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the 3 c's answer ( clear, concise, and courteous )!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure I understand your question, but it seems like you want a function that will create a dynamically allocated array of `struct s_stream` objects and return them to the caller.  If that's the case, it's pretty easy:

```
void easiest(void)
{
  struct s_stream *array = malloc(20 * sizeof(struct s_stream));
}
```

You could move the `malloc()` off into its own function and return the pointer:

```
void caller(void)
{
   struct s_stream *array = create_array(20);
}

struct s_stream *create_array(int count)
{
  return malloc(count * sizeof(struct s_stream));
}
```

Or if you insist on passing the array as a parameter:

```
void caller(void)
{
   struct s_stream *array;
   create_array(&array, 20);
}

void create_array(struct s_stream **array, int count)
{
  *array = malloc(count * sizeof(struct s_stream));
}
```

Comment: Your first `create_array()` should return `void*` shouldn't it? Or better `struct stream*` to be type-safe.

Comment: Yup - typo.  I'll fix it when I get back to a computer.

Comment: Fixed - copy/paste error when I was writing the answer under a bit of time pressure.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're not using a regular array? For example;

```
struct s_stream* streamArray = malloc(sizeof(s_stream*structCount));
```

Then you have an array of s_stream you can just access with streamArray[0] to streamArray[structCount-1] without dereferencing any extra pointers.

Comment: That's the way I was doing it originally.  But I am trying to use qsort on the array (which is 2.4 million members), and the heavy recursion caused stack overflows.  So trying to use and sort pointers instead....